# ¿Como resolver numéricamente ecuaciones de la forma y^3 + (a + bx^2)*y^2 = cx^2 donde las variables son x e y?

Tags: matlab

Estoy tratando de resolver en matlab una ecuación tipo:

[image: ecuacion 1]

donde la variable independiente es x, como producto final debo graficar x contra y.

Espero alguien me pueda colaborar

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! ☺ No olvides visitar el [recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender más acerca de este sitio. Realmente necesitas incluir más detalles en tu pregunta para que la comunidad pueda responder satisfactoriamente. En el [Centro de Ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help) encontrarás [*¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?*](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Puedes editar tu pregunta [aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/40392/edit).

Comment: has intentado [fplot](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/fplot.html)?

Comment: @ArieCwHat muchas gracias por la sugerencia

Comment: @Maguz ya logré solucionar la ecuación, muchas gracias por preguntar :)

Comment: function y = resol(A,B,C,x)
syms z
k = z^3+(A+B*x^2)*z^2-C*x^2;
z = double(solve(k));
y=z(1);
end   clc,clear,close

% Variables generales
teta=24;
x=[10:2:300];

Comment: % % % % % % % %Variables
alfa1=0.000019003;
E1=8997.961264;
w1=0.002705634;
t1=5.14;
m1=1.000305144;
s1=50.26548246;
B=(w1*w1*m1*m1*E1)/(24*t1*t1);
C=w1*w1*E1/24;

% % % % % % % %Temp=15°C
teta1=15;
A1=alfa1*E1*(teta1-teta)-t1;

for i=1:length(x)
y11(i)=resol(A1,B,C,x(i));
end
y1=y11*s1;

% % % % % % % %Temp=20°C
teta2=20;
A2=alfa1*E1*(teta2-teta)-t1;

for i=1:length(x)
y22(i)=resol(A2,B,C,x(i));
end
y2=y22*s1;

% % % % % % % %Temp=25°C
teta3=25;
A3=alfa1*E1*(teta3-teta)-t1;

Comment: @claudia P. Pero en las respuestas, no en los comentarios :p

Comment: @Claudia deberías publicarlo como respuesta  más abajo

Comment: No se como se hace en matlab pero una vez logre hacerlo en c++ con la notación polaca inversa, es la manera mas sencilla de ingresar ecuaciones en una caja de texto o por consola y das valores tanto a X y Y.

Answer (score 1):

(Publicado por la OP en comentarios)

@Maguz ya logré solucionar la ecuación, muchas gracias por preguntar :)

```
function y = resol(A,B,C,x) syms z k = z^3+(A+Bx^2)*z^2-Cx^2; 
z = double(solve(k)); 
y=z(1); 
end clc,clear,close % Variables generales teta=24; 
x=[10:2:300]; 

% % % % % % % %Variables alfa1=0.000019003; 
E1=8997.961264; 
w1=0.002705634; 
t1=5.14; 
m1=1.000305144; 
s1=50.26548246; 
B=(w1*w1*m1*m1*E1)/(24*t1*t1); 
C=w1*w1*E1/24; % % % % % % % %Temp=15°C teta1=15; 
A1=alfa1*E1*(teta1-teta)-t1; 
for i=1:length(x) y11(i)=resol(A1,B,C,x(i)); 
end y1=y11*s1; 
% % % % % % % %Temp=20°C teta2=20; 
A2=alfa1*E1*(teta2-teta)-t1; 
for i=1:length(x) y22(i)=resol(A2,B,C,x(i)); 
end y2=y22*s1; 
% % % % % % % %Temp=25°C teta3=25; 
A3=alfa1*E1*(teta3-teta)-t1;
```